# Comparing csv files in python to see what is in both

Tags: python, csv, comparison

I have 2 csv files that I want to compare one of which is a master file of all the countries and then another one that has only a few countries. This is an attempt I made for some rudimentary testing:

```
char = {}
with open('all.csv', 'rb') as lookupfile:
    for number, line in enumerate(lookupfile):
        chars[line.strip()] = number

with open('locations.csv') as textfile:
    text = textfile.read()
    print text
for char in text:
    if char in chars:
        print("Country found {0} found in row {1}".format(char, chars[char]))
```

I am trying to get a final output of the master file of countries with a secondary column indicating if it came up in the other list

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Write a function to turn the CSV into a Python dictionary containing as keys each of the country you found in the CSV. It can just look like this:

`{'US':True, 'UK':True}`

- Do this for both CSV files.
- Now, iterate over the `dictionary.keys()` for the csv you're comparing against, and just check to see if the other dictionary has the same key.

This will be an extremely fast algorithm because dictionaries give us constant time lookup, and you have a data structure which you can easily use to see which countries you found.

As Eric mentioned in comments, you can also use [set membership](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets) to handle this. This may actually be the simpler, better way to do this:

```
set1 = set()                   # A new empty set
set1.add("country")
if country in set:
  #do something
```

Comment: Im fairly new to python so would I have to make a key for everything in the  csv file like you have shown as a variable?

Comment: If you're only comparing countries, then you'd just need to make keys for the countries. dict[country] = True. @EricLevieil The problem with sets is lookups have an O(n) worst case.

Comment: @CalvinFroedge https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
Sets and dictionary are in the same boat...

Comment: @EricLevieil Ah, you're right, I thought dictionary lookups were always O(1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use exactly the same logic as the original loop:

```
with open('locations.csv') as textfile:
    for line in textfile:
        if char.strip() in chars:
            print("Country found {0} found in row {1}".format(char, chars[char]))
```